# Updating the MYSQL table fails

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am having two tables named task_details and task_detail_folder_mapping.
I can create task and save in any folder even I can create a subtask for the main task.

```
if main task's id is 21 and its parent id will be 0. If it is having subtask then say task id=22 and parent id=21
```

If I want to delete that main task then its subtask should be automatically deleted and in the table task_details both these tasks are set to 1 after deleting.

This is happening in the task_details table. But in the task_detail_folder_mapping only main task is set to 1. Its subtask is still 0 in the is_deleted field of task_detail_folder_mapping table.

Model :

```
public function delete_task()
    {
        // Debugging messages to be saved as text files.
        $str_class_name = get_class($this) . " --> " . __FUNCTION__ . " --> ".__LINE__;
        log_message("debug", $str_class_name);

        $int_task_id    =   $this->input->get('task_id');


        $mix_result_mapping =   $this->MY_Model->update_data (
                                                                'task_detail_folder_mapping',
                                                                array('is_deleted' => 1),
                                                                array('task_id' => $int_task_id));


        $mix_result_parent_task =   $this->MY_Model->update_data(
                                                                    'task_details',
                                                                    array('is_deleted' => 1),
                                                                    array('task_id' =>  $int_task_id)); 

        $mix_result_sub_task    =   $this->MY_Model->update_data(
                                                                    'task_details',
                                                                    array('is_deleted' => 1),
                                                                    array('parent_task_id' => $int_task_id)); 

        $mix_return_value = ($mix_result_mapping  && $mix_result_parent_task && $mix_result_sub_task) ? TRUE : FALSE;
        return $mix_return_value;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function delete_task()
        { 
            $mix_result =   $this->task_manager_model->delete_task();

            if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
            {
                $mix_return_value = ($mix_result) ? TRUE : FALSE;
                echo $mix_return_value;
            }
        }
```

view :

```
<input type="hidden" name="task_id" id="task_id" />
```

Thanks in advance!!!! I need help

Comment: I think you have different task_id and parent_task_id, You have used same in where condition...

Comment: Sorry I didn't  get you.

Comment: i think you should design database by assigning relationship to the columns...So,in phpmyadmin Go to "Designer" menu and select "Add relation" option and assign relationship between common columns

Comment: There is relationship between tables thats why the main task is deleted from the task_detail_folder_mapping table

Comment: Here I wrote a query to get task_id of that task whose parent id = task id. Like  $int_task_id    =   $this->input->get('task_id'); $int_parent_task_id=$this->db->query("SELECT task_id FROM task_details where parent_id='".$int_task_id."'"); Here I will get the task_id of the sub task but When I will try to update the task_detail_folder_mapping table with that id the table is not updating